# Firefox doesn't select contenteditable text properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, contenteditable

I'm trying to implement inline editing of elements in a web app. I'm doing this with `contenteditable` in order to preserve formatting as the user is editing an element.

After the user double clicks on an element, I change set it's `contenteditable` property to `true` and select the text (using the method from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)) so that they can begin editing right away without having to select the text. This works as expected in Chrome and Safari (don't care about IE). **However, in Firefox, the text does get selected, but it's not editable until you deselect and reselect the text manually.** (e.g. if you double click on an element, it gets selected, but if you start typing to edit the selected text, nothing will happen)

I've tried `stopPropagation()`, `preventDefault()` and `execCommand('selectAll', false, null)` to no avail.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76Aku/) to show you what I'm talking about. Try it in Chrome/Safari and Firefox to see what the problem is in Firefox.

```
$('#title').dblclick(function(){
    $('#title').attr({'contenteditable' : true});
    $('#title').css({'border-bottom' : '3px dashed #E3E1E4'});            
    selectText('title'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to the dblclick handler:

```
$('#title').focus();
```

Comment: Whoops, I had to do this exact same thing in another place as a fix for Firefox, I should have known that. Thanks anyways, hopefully this will help someone else. For anyone wondering, you also need to add a `$('#title').blur();` when you turn contenteditable off